# Ruby unpack to Python

Tags: python, ruby, struct, unpack

I'm trying to convert some Ruby code into Python. I'm having troubles with this line:

```
Digest::MD5.digest(message).unpack('L*')
```

I think I should use the `struct` module and the `hashlib` one, but if I do:

```
struct.unpack('L', hashlib.md5(message).digest())
```

I get this error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 4
```

What should I do?
Thank you,

rubik

P.S. The output should be a list of 4 x 32 bit ints:

```
irb(main):039:0> Digest::MD5.digest('Hash').unpack('L*')
=> [631892218, 1967199614, 3683860954, 4130231798]
```

Comment: DId you try `struct.unpack('LLLL', hashlib.md5(message).digest())`? If this doesn't work, please provide a sample of your message.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Wow it works! Can you please give an explanation of the `LLLL` format? Thank you!

Comment: `LLLL` means "4 32 bits ints". So if you want 4 32 bits ints, you use `LLLL` format and not `L` format which is only 1 32 bits int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for arbitrary length unpacks (the `*` operator). You'll have to specify a repeater manually.

Luckily the struct module does let you specify a fixed length, *and* the hashlib module tells you how many bytes to expect. By putting an integer number *before* the `L` you specify the number of times to apply the pattern. And a specific hash in the `hashlib` library has a [`.digest_size` attribute](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest_size) that tells you how many bytes long a specific hash is.

To combine these:

```
structspec = '%iL' % (hashlib.hash('md5').digest_size / 4)
struct.unpack(structspec, hashlib.md5(message).digest())
```

If you don't even want to hardcode the `4` there, you can ask `struct.calcsize` for the size of an `L` unsigned long as well:

```
structspec = '%iL' % (hashlib.hash('md5').digest_size / struct.calcsize('L'))
struct.unpack(structspec, hashlib.md5(message).digest())
```

In fact, on 64 bit platforms like my Mac, `L` is 8 bytes, so the latter calculation matters enormously if you are deploying across different architectures.

Answer (score 2):

`struct.unpack('L', ...)` will only unpack a single long from the parameter. What you want to do is extract all, unlike Ruby, Pythons unpack function does not have the ability to unpack an arbitrary amount of values, instead you must repeat the format specifier.

```
hash = hashlib.md5(message).digest()
struct.unpack('L' * (len(hash) / 4), hash)
```

This will repeat the `'L'` as many times as the string allows and unpack all the ints in the hash and return a tuple with len / 4 items in it. If you want the result as a list, simple cast it to one with `list()`.

Comment: Alternatively, 'nL' will also work, with `n` being an integer number.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want 4 longs, the format is 'LLLL':

```
struct.unpack('LLLL', hashlib.md5(message).digest())
```